# Does High Sugar Concentration Inhibits Bacterial growth?

Tags: fermentation, techniques, ingredients, sugar, bacteria

About a month ago, I started making a dairy-free drink with blended fruit (i.e. Strawberries, Raspberries, etc). I'd like to start lacto-fermenting these smoothies but a friend of mine insists that the sugar content is too high and it would be impossible for bacteria to grow in it.

Can bacteria (namely Lactobacillus) grow in high concentrations of sugar? If not, why and would the sugar content of my blended fruit be too high to allow bacteria fermentation? Would it be possible to lacto-ferment things like Orange Juice or Apple Juice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Osmotic pressure does retard cell devision in most micro organisms making it hard to grow "in" a dense solution but they will have no problem growing "on" such a solution. High sugar content does little to inhibit growth of bacteria and yeast as long as it's still a solution and not a "gel".

That being said, you can sour your juices you mentioned with lacto just fine.

Comment: Thanks Evil, great response. One last thing: Could you explain what you mean, when you say "as long as it's still a solution and not a 'gel.'"

Comment: @Wilhelm thick like jello

Comment: It's more the texture or a milk shake. Thanks for your help.